# create and reuse html content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create html content that i need to embed in a url and send to an api (Dreamhost mailing api).

> https://api.dreamhost.com/?cmd=announcement_list-post_announcement&message="here
>   commes html content"

the html is the content of a mail (html formatted)

I wonder how I do this best. Can I use a layout and grab the content of the layout?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a partial and save the result as a string

```
html = render_to_string :partial => 'mails/template'
```